# Meaning of "I'll hardly have time for a rubber"?

Tags: meaning

I encountered this expression in the book Sea Glass by Anita Shreve and can't figure out what it means. (Actually, I have a few ideas but want to know the correct meaning.)

> "I'll hardly have time for a rubber before we land."

A woman is talking about her upcoming trip on a luxury plane, a cabin with six rooms. The time is 1929. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Providing she isn't travelling alone, I would assume she refers to a [card game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_bridge).

Comment: I would assume a card game.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't indicated which expression you're referring to, but the only part of the sentence that seems potentially obscure is the noun *rubber*, so I'll assume that that's what you're asking about.

The relevant sense of *rubber* seems to be (quoting from [the English Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rubber)):

> […] a match consisting of the best of a series of three games in bridge or whist.

(The speaker is continuing the thought from the end of her previous sentence: "the club chairs pivot so you can play cards".)

Answer (score 1):

Chambers Dictionary defines a rubber as follows; In the card games of Bridge and Whist a rubber is the winning of, or play for, the best of three games (sometimes five). The word can also be generally used for any spell of card playing or for a series of games in various sports such as cricket, tennis or bowls.

John L.

Comment: Cricket, tennis and bowls would all require some ingenuity to play on board a plane.

Comment: @Erik But now that you mention it ...